# Upload file as a new thread in java web application

Tags: java, asyncfileupload

I have a web application with upload file functionality. If the filesize/no:of rows in the spreadsheet is more, then the upload should happen in a seperate thread and the user will be shown a message "upload will happen offline, you may proceed to next page" .

My question:
1. If I close the browser while the thread is still processing the file. Does it cause the thread to stop ? I am not sure whether the thread has anything to do with the user session.

Comment: why don't you try and see?

Comment: I have another solution which anyway I am trying out(putting the upload info into a que and file to another location, and file processing is done using a message driven bean). If anyone has experience on the scenario mentioned in the question above please advice.